# How to setup minheight for svg element in ui resizable widget?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to setup minimum height for resizable svg element. i can setup minimum height for resizable widget but not for the content inside div. i have dynamic svg element instead of div. right now for example i have shown as div instead of svg element.

```
 $('#resize').resizable({
helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
  minHeight:150,
 grid: [10, 10]
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gs3xpxhr/3/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/gs3xpxhr/4/

```
 $('#resize').resizable({
helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
grid: [10, 10],
minHeight:150
});
```